# I want to check whether the user supplied Credentials (Through Edit Text box) match with the values in my DB coulms ID. 

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Here is my Cursor code, what I am confused about is how do I go on checking each value and make my boolean valued x true or false based on the computation:

```
  private boolean fillData() {
       Cursor c = DBHelper.fetchAllIDs();
       // List<String> idList = new ArrayList<String>();
       if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String X = (c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("IDno")));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" +X, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (Idno.getText().toString().equals(X));
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),   ""+Idno.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                x=true;
            }
        } while (c.moveToNext());


       }
      return x;
   }
```

Comment: 1. I don't quite follow what you're trying to do here. 2. Don't use == for String comparison: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus

Comment: I want to compare each element I fetch from my database through this code with a value supplied by the user and if they match I want x to be true, what happens here is that even if a user supplies a different value than fetched my x still becomes true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. set `x` to false before looping on the cursor.

   ```
   private boolean fillData() {
       boolean x = false;

       // ...

   }
   ```
2. replace the following code:

   ```
   if (Idno.getText().toString().equals(X));
   {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),   ""+Idno.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       x=true;
   }
   ```

   with this:

   ```
   if (Idno.getText().toString().equals(X))
   {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),   ""+Idno.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       x=true;
       break;
   }
   ```

   **notice**:
   i removed the `;` from the end of the `if` statement, and added a `break` statement at the end of the `if` block.